# How to change shortcuts in Bluefish?

Tags: bluefish

Is it possible to change shortcuts in Bluefish?

There is an old guide at http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/manual/ch08.html, but the information there doesn't seem applicable to version 2.0.

Modifying `menudump` in `Bluefish` folder doesn't help either.

I'm using version 2.2.4.1

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn't changed.

1. Highlight the menu with the shortcut.
2. Push the backspace key.
3. Press a new key combination.

If you want to changes to be permanent (and not only for the session) Edit > Save shortcut keys.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, at least not on Ubuntu 12.04. Pushing the backspace doesn't do anything and there isn't such thing as Edit > Save shortcut keys.

Comment: OK, it does work, but only with 2.2.4. installed through PPA and not through Ubuntu Softwere Center. Anyway, thank you for your help. Also, Edit > Save shortcut keys doesn't seem to be necessary anymore, it saves new shortcuts automatically.

Answer (score 0):

bluefish 2.2.12
(on KDE/Plasma)

as OP wrote: no menu entry (it's in the settings dialog)
pressing shortcuts when menu ishighlighted does nothing,
and BACKSPACE does nothing.

however, modifying `~/.bluefish/menudump`  does work, under these conditions:

1. must restart bluefish after changes
2. remove the `;` in front of edited line. otherwise `;` means line is commented out, and has no effect. (it's an archaeological remnant)
3. there's no collision test: before entering a shortcut, make sure it's not assigned elsewhere in the file.

Cool and sexy it is not.

Also note:
ctrl key here is:

I assume the "backspace-highligh" trick (which is also archaeological remnant) works in certain Gnome environmnet, but not in others. It's extremely error prone, bad UI/UX, shitty way to assign shortcuts, though, and I wouldn't do it even if it was working in my environment.